# How to use protractor helper? Any documentation that I can refer to execute this?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am using protractor version @5.4.1
I came across protractor helper and installed it using

```
npm install —save @types/protractor-helper
```

A separated folder is created at a location where I have both `nodemodules` and `protractor`

I tried executing protractor by using

```
 protractor conf.js
```

after adding protractor helper in `config.js` but it's throwing as error: **cannot find module protractor-helper**.

Conf.js
Exports.config ={
Framework:’jasmine’,
SeleniumAddress :’ ‘,
Specs :[..],
Capabilities:{
‘BrowserName’:’Internet explorer’, ‘version’:’11’,
AcceptSslcrts:true,
TrustAllSSLCertificates:false,
ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS:true,
},
SeleniumserverJar:’..’,

geckodriver:’ ..’
};

Is there any link or document to get a clear idea of using protractor helper

Comment: Can you put the exact error (copy-paste) in your question? Also, the `protractor.conf.js`, or at least the relevant part?

Comment: i am new to protractor helper functions so i am not sure how to use it in confg. Js and spec file po protractor

Comment: I know - maybe you can simply paste the whole protractor.conf.js file so we can see how are you using it?

Comment: Show your conf.js

Answer (score 0):

Ali, to install the protractor-helper you must use:

`npm install protractor-helper`

The documentation is here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-helper

And you don't use on config.js, but in your tests and page objects.
See a example here:
[Gihub repository - Protractor style guide](https://github.com/PauloGoncalvesBH/protractor-style-guide)